# How many solutions does $x^{\sqrt{5}}=1$ have?

Tags: polynomials, roots, exponentiation, quadratics, transcendental-equations

Because $x^2=1$ has 2 solutions. $x^3=1$ has 3 solutions in complex numbers. So should $x^{\sqrt{5}}=1$ have 2 and a bit solutions?!!!

Or does it have infinite solutions? If we say the solution to $x^n=1$ is to go a fraction $m/n$ around a circle for any $m$.

If we go a 'fraction' $m/\sqrt{5}$ around a circle for any $m$ this is an infinite number of solution!

What is wrong here? Is there notation of powers self consistent?

Comment: $\frac{2\pi i k}{n}$ since $k = n $ if $ k \in \mathbb{Z}$ you get finite number of solutions because they will repeat after $k > n$, i.e $k\mod n$. In this case $n=\sqrt{5}$ so you won't find any cycle for $k$ so you have infinite solutions.

Answer (score 5):

**Added later**:  I'm leaving this answer as is, for what it's worth.  But Christian Blatter's thorough analysis makes it clear that sometimes what seems safe to say is anything but.  I jumped too quickly to formal manipulations, overlooking the fact that one must deal first with what is meant by an expression of the form $x^\alpha$ when the power is not an integer. (End of edit.)

Since $1=e^{2\pi in}$ if and only if $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, we can safely say that

$$x^\sqrt5=1\iff x=e^{2\pi in/\sqrt5}=\cos\left(2\pi n\over \sqrt5\right)+i\sin\left(2\pi n\over\sqrt5\right)\quad\text{with }n\in\mathbb{Z}$$

For example, $x\approx-0.9455+0.3256i$ is a solution (corresponding to $n=1$).

As for $x^\sqrt5=1$ having "$2$ and a bit solutions" in analogy to $x^2$ and $x^3$ having $2$ and $3$ solutions, respectively, would you also say that $x^0=1$ has $0$ solutions, or $x^{-1}=1$ has $-1$ solutions?

Comment: But if put n from 1 to infinity you would get any point on the circle to any accuracy you liked!

Answer (score 4):

You can say it has a real solution, because you take logarithm of both sides and it gives you

$$\sqrt 5\log x=0$$

so

$$x=1$$

is a solution.

You can not really talk about the solutions for $x$ negative or complex if you have not defined how you compute powers for complex numbers.

One way of doing that is defining a complex logarithme (which won't be defined on all $\mathbb C$), but there are several definitions for logarithm, and you have to add some context if you want to study the number of solutions on $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @OscarLanzi could you explain why?

Comment: I like this answer best of all, ’cause it makes clear the role of opinion in the formulation of any answer. You may not like my definition of logarithm, after all.

Answer (score 2):

Before we can look at your equation we have to make sense of the term $x^{\sqrt{5}}$. For rational exponents ${p\over q}$ we can define $x^{p/q}:=\root q\of {x^p}$. As $\sqrt{5}$ is irrational we would have to choose a sequence $(r_n)_{n\geq1}$ of rational numbers that converges to $\sqrt{5}$, and hope that the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} x^{r_n}=:x^{\sqrt{5}}$ exists, and is independent of the chosen sequence.

Since some limiting procedure is called for anyway one takes a more elegant route to powers with arbitrary real (or complex) exponents. After introducing the exponential function $\exp:\>{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}_{>0}$ and $\log:\>{\mathbb R}_{>0}\to{\mathbb R}$ one defines
$$x^\alpha:=\exp(\alpha\log x)\qquad (x>0,\quad\alpha\in{\mathbb R})\ .\tag{1}$$
In this way $(x,\alpha)\mapsto x^\alpha$ is continuous in its variables $x$ and $\alpha$ wherever defined, and obeys the well known rules of "power algebra".
If we want $x^\alpha=1$ in this context this implies $\alpha\log x=0$, or $(\alpha=0)\vee(\log x=0)$. As $\alpha=\sqrt{5}$ in the example at hand we are left with $\log x=0$, hence $x=1$, as only solution.

In the complex environment the defining formula $(1)$ is extended to
$$z^\alpha:={\rm pv}\bigl(z^\alpha\bigr):=\exp\bigl(\alpha\,{\rm Log}(z) \bigr)\qquad (z\in\Omega,\quad\alpha\in{\mathbb C})\ ,$$
where $\Omega$ denotes the complex plane with the negative real axis removed. Any $z\in\Omega$ can be written in the form $$z=r\,e^{i\phi},\qquad r>0,\quad |\phi|<\pi\ ,$$
and one  has $${\rm Log}(z):=\log r+i\phi\ .$$
The given equation  then amounts to
$$\sqrt{5}(\log r+i\phi)=2k\pi i, \qquad k\in{\mathbb Z},\quad|\phi|<\pi\ .$$
This leads to $\log r =0$, hence $r=1$, and to
$$\phi={2k\over\sqrt{5}}\pi\ .$$
The condition $|\phi|<\pi$ then implies that necessarily $k\in\{-1,0,1\}$, so that we obtain three solutions in all.

Comment: Are you saying that $x=e^{4\pi i/\sqrt5}$ is not a solution to $x^\sqrt5=1$?

Comment: @BarryCipra: Tell me your definition of $x^{\sqrt{5}}$. – If $x^{\sqrt{5}}$ is a set valued function, to be defined properly, then $x^{\sqrt{5}}=1$ makes no sense, only $1\in x^{\sqrt{5}}$ does. In this case the envisaged set is dense in $S^1$. I don't know whether the OP had this in mind.

Comment: You are quite right.  I clearly need to revise my answer!  (I'll do so when I have a bit more time.)

Answer (score 0):

In the complex numbers, we define $x^a=e^{a \log x}$  The logarithm is multivalued because $e^{2 \pi i}=1$, so $e^b = e^{2n\pi i+b}$ for any integer $n$.  Given that  $x=1$ is a solution, then $x=1+\frac {2n\pi i}{ \sqrt 5}$ is also a solution for any integer $n$..  Yes, there are an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: $(1+2n\pi i)^{\sqrt5}=1$????

Comment: The edit is still wrong.  Did you drink decaf by mistake this morning? ;-)